# PhpStorm code completing for Twig templates

Tags: twig, phpstorm

When accessing a method via a Twig template the method name is always shortened and the prefix is removed.

For example: `{{ object.getName }}` gets completed to `{{ object.name }}` whenever I try to use the full method name, code completion will show nothing but if the full method name is finally entered manually it resolves the method just fine and I can jump to it.

I really really dislike this but could not find a way to disable the behavior. Is it even possible or someone can give me a hint what to do about it?

Comment: Do you have Symfony plugin installed and enabled for this project? AFAIK such completion must be provided by the Symfony plugin (because standard Twig plugin by JetBrains does little for method completion and _especially_ replacements like that). https://symfony2-plugin.espend.de/languages/twig/index.html Please check that with Symfony plugin author: https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin

Comment: ok thanks for the info. i have checked the repository and found the method in the `TwigTypeResolveUtil` Class. Sadly this behavior is **not configurable**.